# Publish .NET application with 3rd party binaries

Tags: .net, f#

i have a dotnet application. it utilizes some 3rd party tool binaries. program retrieves paths to 3rd party tools by environment variables through iconfiguration like this:

`configuration.GetValue<string> ("ToolPath", "")`

how can i include these 3rd party binaries when publishing the application.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy 3rd party tools into published directory and update environment variables.